# Merge columns in reportlab table

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am trying to create a table with `reportlab` that can have values that need to be merged across all or certain columns.

This is my example, where I need the first row to be merged across all five columns. I tried with the `('SPAN', (0, 0), (-1, -1))` line, which is commented in this example, so that you can see how the table looks initially. If I uncomment that line, I only get the first row written to the pdf.

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib import colors

width, height = A4
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles["BodyText"]
styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT
styleBH = styles["Normal"]
styleBH.alignment = TA_CENTER

def coord(x, y, unit=1):
    x, y = x * unit, height - y * unit
    return x, y

# Headers
head = Paragraph('''<b>Table head</b>''', styleBH)
hID = Paragraph('''<b>ID</b>''', styleBH)
hcount = Paragraph('''<b>count</b>''', styleBH)
hcandidate = Paragraph('''<b>candidate</b>''', styleBH)
hprice = Paragraph('''<b>price</b>''', styleBH)
htotal_price = Paragraph('''<b>total price</b>''', styleBH)

# Texts
description = Paragraph('long paragraph', styleN)
ID = Paragraph('1', styleN)
count = Paragraph('120', styleN)
price = Paragraph('$52.00', styleN)
total_price = Paragraph('$6240.00', styleN)

data = [[head],
    [hID, hcount, hcandidate, hprice, htotal_price],
        [ID, description, description, price, total_price]]

table = Table(data, colWidths=[2.05 * cm, 2.7 * cm, 5 * cm,
                               3 * cm, 3 * cm])

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
    # ('SPAN', (0, 0), (-1, -1)),
    ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.grey),
    ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
    ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
]))

c = canvas.Canvas('output_pdf.pdf', pagesize=A4)
table.wrapOn(c, width, height)
table.drawOn(c, *coord(1.8, 9.6, cm))
c.save()
```

I surfed through questions here but I did not find any clear example on how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 16):

*(0,0) refers to start cell at top extreme left  and (-1,-1) refers to end cell at the bottom extreme right.*

change your `('SPAN', (0, 0), (-1, -1))` to `('SPAN', (0, 0), (4, 0))`

> SPAN, (sc,sr), (ec,er) indicates that the cells in columns sc - ec and
>   rows sr - er should be combined into a super cell with contents
>   determined by the cell (sc, sr).

If I tried to explain in a mathematical way i.e matrix representation it would be merge matrix[0][0] and matrix[0][4].
I know, its little bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you tell me what the letters sc, sr, ec, er mean? I'm guessing the `c` and `r` are column and row. But what is the `s` and `e`?

Comment: your guess is correct. `s` is for start and `e` is for end